# Regex to contain one of three characters?

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex that matches strings that has one of three characters say just x, y and z. I tried `"[xyz]^"` but it doesn't work. The string may containe any other characters but must contain at least one of the three given characters in any order or position

Comment: Just `/[xyz]/` should be good enough for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
 ^.*[xyz].*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mwpG_jJgwc_akS9i)

Answer (score 3):

### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pE6xI3)

```
\b\w*(x|y|z)\w*\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wLTf5cv6okKQYNLF)

```
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
\w* match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
1st Capturing group (x|y|z)
    1st Alternative: x
        x matches the character x literally (case sensitive)
    2nd Alternative: y
        y matches the character y literally (case sensitive)
    3rd Alternative: z
        z matches the character z literally (case sensitive)
\w* match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should match:

```
^.*[xyz].*$
```

In python :

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^.*[xyz].*$', 'AzE')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2643718>
>>> re.match(r'^.*[xyz].*$', 'AEz')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2643cc8>
>>> re.match(r'^.*[xyz].*$', 'AE')
>>>
```